# Per-field Firebase Rules for Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a database on Cloud Firestore with a collection `users`. Each user has write access to their own `user` document, but that `user` document also contains data such as `isAdmin`. How can I restrict the `isAdmin` field to be read-only, while giving them write access to other fields?

Thanks

Comment: You can't.  Either someone can read and entire document, or they can't read it at all.  You will have to split the document into two, in different collections, and give each collection different permissions.

Comment: A way to get around this is by having another collection of Admin Users that only admins can edit

Comment: Well you can.... Just write in your rule that the field "isadmin"should not be changed: request.resource.data.isAdmin == resource.data.isAdmin